# How to always run bundle install with the --full-index option

Tags: ruby, bundler

Is there a way to configure bundler so that it always runs install with `--full-index` rather than having to specify it each time? Either per Gemfile or system-wide.

Answer (score 1):

For this and other Bundler options, I've found the best way is to use a shell function (or alias):

`function bi { bundle install --standalone --binstubs --full-index $*; }`

Some options (e.g., `--path`) are stored in `.bundle/config` the first time they are used.  But if you don't want to have to remember whether you used them yet, you can put them in your shell function as well.